# Image Cropping with another image overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to crop an image and let it fit in another image with both images merging together as one. Is this possible with JS? Please suggest any suitable plugin with examples.
Thanks

Comment: This isn't a place to ask for plugins. You're expected to have at least tried to resolve this for yourself.

Comment: Looks like a job for google! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this with [CSS masks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) - no JS needed!

```
.some-class {
    mask: url(mask.png);  
}
```